# how can i use '\' in php

Tags: php, string, str-replace

anyone know how i can use

```
$utf8string = str_replace('\',"&#92;",$utf8string);
```

in php?
because i cant use ' after \ and its give me an error
and if i write

```
$utf8string = str_replace('\ ',"&#92;",$utf8string);
```

its not do what i want
and

```
$utf8string = str_replace("\","&#92;",$utf8string);
```

not work too
so what i must to do?
i want update mysql but if end of my text have \ its not work and give me an error
like this query

```
update phpfox_comment_text set text_parsed = 'nakheir\',text = '' where comment_id = 197597
```

there is 400.000 query i want to update but i must replace \ with \ cuz i get this error always

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php. And I feel obliged to inform you that you have a gaping SQL injection hole, and probably are using the deprecated `mysql_` extensions, and that you should use PDO or MySQLi and parametrized queries.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `\\` instead of just `\`.

A `\` has special meaning inside a string as it is used for escaping. To mean a literal `\` you need to escape it!! By preceding it with a, well `\`.

Comment: damn it was so fast and you make my life easy now :D thank you

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `\` with another `\`.

```
$utf8string = str_replace("\\","&#92;",$utf8string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$utf8string = str_replace('\\',"&#92;",$utf8string);
```

Answer (score 1):

"\" is a "meta-character.

If you want, you can "escape" it by using `"\\"`.